# Im unable to fill the page with a solid background color and whatever I try it just doesnt seem to work without scrollbar

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

```
<div>
            <body class="body m-0 p-0 justify-center items-center font-['Jost',sans-serif] overflow-hidden flex bg-fuchsia-300">
                <div class="w-[320px] h-[450px] mt-20 ">
                    <div class="login bg-[#fff] transition ease-in-out duration-[0.8s]" >
                        <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
                                    <label class="flex ml-10 font-bold pt-4 pb-1 text-3xl">Sign in</label>
                                    <p class="ml-10 pb-3 text-sm ">Explore the infinite possibilities</p>
                                    <input class="w-60 h-10 mx-auto my-3 text-[#573b8a] justify-center flex rounded-[4px] font-medium indent-1.5 border-[1px] border-b-[1px] border-b-[#949090] border-[#b4adad] mb-6"  type="email" placeholder="Email" value={email} name="email" required="" onChange={onChange} />
                                    <input class="w-60 h-10 mx-auto my-3 mb-2 text-[#573b8a] justify-center flex rounded-[4px] font-medium indent-1.5 border-[1px] border-b-[1px] border-b-[#949090] border-[#b4adad]" type="password" placeholder="Password" value={password} name='password' required="" onChange={onChange} />
                                    <Link class="ml-10 text-red-600 text-sm hover:text-blue-500" to='/forgotPassword'>Forgot password?</Link>
                                        <button class="mt-4 w-60 h-[40px] bg-purple-800 rounded-full justify-center block my-[10px] mx-auto p-[10px] text-[1em] hover:bg-blue-700">Log In</button>
                                        {/* <a  className="link ui blue" href="./signup">Sign Up</a> */}
                                        <br  />
                                        
                                        <br />
                                        
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <Link to="/register">Sign Up</Link>
                </div>
            </body>
        </div>
```

**I'm trying to create this login form but I can't quite get the background to fill and I'm unable to where I make tweaks to fix the issue and I tried setting the "height value to screen" in the body class but it doesnt seem to work well. And also theres some extra white space beneath the login button and I cant get rid of it as well. It'd be really helpful if someone can tell me what I should change in order to achieve the mentioned. Ive attached a pic to make to clarify the issue better.**
[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBHH0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

All html tags like div, p etc should be inside of body tag, in your example code you have div tag first and then body which is not correct.
About white spaces there could be multiple reason, like margin, padding or height related issue of your parent html tag.

For exact solution:
Can you share your live website URL, I can let you know exact reason and solution for this issue

Comment: I havent yet hosted the site so I won't be able to share a working link but I've added the div tag as its necessary in react when I'm returning the function , the html code to be included inside the div tag..else it gives me error. Most importantly I want to fix the background of the page to a solid color without having vertical scrolls in the page. But when I add "height: screen" the background is filled but theres always a vertical scroll thatI can't get rid off.

Comment: You can add property on same div where you are adding hight.     overflow:hidden